# Solar panel array interference with DVB-T reception

Tags: antenna, solar-energy

We are looking to get solar panels installed, and also currently use DVB-T to get TV via antennas in our attic space.

The solar company has suggested that the EMF from the panels/cabling will make reception hard, if not non-existent, even though we have arranged them leaving a space on the roof where PVC pipes currently poke through the roof, and our antennas are point out via.

How far would the EMF field travel from ~300 watt panels/cabling right behind them that is routed "around" the area of the antennas, emanate?

Is it realistic to have panels sitting on either side of a ~3 foot gap that has antennas behind looking out through that gap, causing so much interference that even with an amplifier a decent quality+strength of TV signal won't be able to be received?

Comment: *causing so much interference* The panels probably don't cause any interference, they just **shield** the signals. Since the solar panels are electrically conductive, they **reflect** RF signals instead of just letting them through (like your roof).

Comment: With high-efficiency (fast-switching) micro-inverters on each panel, there will be lots of RFI.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie - Perhaps it wasn't clear from my question, but I am arranging with the solar company to leave a ~3ft gap between the 2 sets of panels, so I can point the antenna out via that gap, in the direction of the transmission tower. I understood that EM waves emanate in one direction, so not sure how panels not being in the line of sight to the transmitter will affect reception if there is no/not significant enough EMF from panels/wires. I am not good at the wavelength calculations, but is ~3ft too small for all lower VHF channels to not be clipped/induced into the metal in the panels?

Comment: Thanks @analogsystemsrf. That makes sense, though with the micro-inverters being on the outside of the roof (I assume), and with cables routed along the perimeter of the roof line (even outside, also, perhaps) are you suggesting that the EMF will induce enough noise into the antenna (I assume, rather than affecting the TV signals themselves) that the signal to noise ratio wouldn't allow all but perhaps the strongest TV signal to be picked up by our TV's tuner?

Comment: Just be prepared for interference. Fast edges (the switching regulator/chopper/60Hz_power_waveform_generation) will correlate with just about any periodic signal (those TV carriers)  and inject upsets to the carrier/modulation/dense_QAM_constellations with resultant Bit Errors.

Comment: *I understood that EM waves emanate in one direction* Those waves can still reflect on the panels. It is impossible to say what will happen without knowing **all** details including the location of the transmitter relative to your antenna. You will just have to try and see what happens.

Comment: I highly doubt that each panel will have its own converter as that is quite inefficient and expensive. Usually the panels are just connected in series/parallel groups and they feed their DC to a converter **inside the house** which will then also be kept nice and dry.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie - Thanks for the comments. Guess I will just have to try it. Both companies that quoted me stated there would be devices attached to each panel, so that one panel shaded will not impact total generation, which apparently will also allow me to see how much power each panel is generating. Not sure if that is a recent change in solar industry practice...

Comment: Putting the electronics on the back of the panel is increasingly common: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_optimizer or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_micro-inverter .

Comment: Does your have a chimney? If so, you could relatively easily relocate the antenna to that. Would limit chance of interference.

Comment: @GlennWillen Thanks for sharing that (new to me) info. I wonder how that solution will compare lifetime/robustness wise against the "electronics in the house" installation. Particularly regarding lifetime of the electronics (water ingress, low and high temperatures). Time will tell I guess.

Comment: @TomCarpenter - Yes, we have a chimney, though 2 stories up and being outside the antennas won't last as long and be subject to movement from weather.

Comment: Here in USA, microInverter on each panel is a common method.

Comment: @user66001 My parents house has an antenna outside on the chimney which has been there for over 30 years and still works perfectly well. This is in Yorkshire, the home of windy rainy miserable weather ;). Many of the houses around have the same.

Comment: @TomCarpenter - Thanks. My opinion on longevity only comes from the state of the antenna on the 30 year old house when we moved in a few years back. Am sure we can agree though that being inside it would surely last longer based on being exposed to none of the corrosive elements of outside. Unfortunately my issue with being up a ladder 2 stories still applies (am very much a do it yourself person so wouldn't be happy paying someone else to be up this ladder ;) )

Answer (score 2):

You should consider moving the antenna or moving the panels to a suitable separate location.

The panels may well act as a large shield given that the panels have metallic strips in and between the cells.

If you continue with the plan of hoping a small gap will still give you tv then it may be expensive trying to sort a solution after, and the Solar company may not be prepared to help as they warned you in advance of the possible issue.

Comment: Thanks @Solar Mike, however this is the only surface that faces south-ish on our house, and given solar is a high priority for us, would happily move the antenna outside (as stated), or somewhere else, rather than ditch the plan to go solar. Just to be clear, your saying that even signal that is emanating in a slightly different direction than the gap will induce enough of it to affect the strength in an adjacent direction?